# Generic class with class-bound constraint cannot be parametrized by class-bound protocol

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I'd like to have a generic weak reference to an object and parametrize it by a protocol that is class-bound.

Here is the code example that does not work in my case:

```
protocol Protocol: class { // also written as `protocol Protocol: AnyObject {`
    func function()
}


final class A: Protocol {
    func function() {}
}

final class Weak<Type> where Type: AnyObject {
    final private weak var property: Type?

    init(property: Type) {
        self.property = property
    }
}

let a = A()
let something = Weak<Protocol>(property: a) // error: 'Weak' requires that 'Protocol' be a class type
```

I get an error on last line: `'Weak' requires that 'Protocol' be a class type`.

As `Protocol` will always be of `class` type (which is the same as `AnyObject`) shouldn't that be allowed by the compiler?
Is it possible to resolve that issue with swift 4?

If not, is it a limitation that can be resolved in a future version of swift or is it something impossible that the type system can not allow to happen?

A not accepted solution is to use `@objc` to the protocol declaration as in:

```
@obc protocol Protocol: class {
    func function()
}
```

as this leads to limitations.

Answer (score 2):

You are saying:

```
final class Weak<Type> where Type: AnyObject {
```

So you yourself are requiring that Type be a class (because that is exactly what AnyObject means).

A protocol is *not* a class. It is a protocol.

Comment: Basically, this is just another case of my https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself. As for the future, might be covered by Hamish's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/341994

Comment: But there is no way to specify a reference type other than `AnyObject`. Currently in swift you can't just declare `final class Weak<Type> where Type: class`.

Comment: But that’s just notation; even if you could, a protocol is not a class. Read the links I gave you...

Answer (score 0):

This is currently impossible because protocols do not conform to themselves. A protocol is not a type; it is a recipe for a type. As the simplest example of why this is hard, consider this situation:

```
protocol X {
    init()
}

func f<T: X>(type: T.Type) -> T {
    return type.init()
}

f(type: X.self)
```

This would create a value of type `X`, but would that be? This isn't allowed, and the mechanism that prevents it is that protocols do not conform to themselves. This crops up in a lots of other ways, and your example is one of them.

Some of this will be addressed when more of the [Generics Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#generalized-existentials) is implemented, particularly the section Generalized Existentials, but currently what you want isn't possible. You can't have a "weak reference to some unknown thing." You need to know what that thing is.

The standard solution to this problem is a box, not a protocol. See [Weak Arrays](https://www.objc.io/blog/2017/12/28/weak-arrays/) for an example.

Comment: I have already found the objc.io Weak Arrays articles. A `WeakBox<A: AnyObject>` has same exact limitation as the example in the question above.

Comment: Agreed; you will need to know your type. You cannot just have a Weak "something." You need to know what that something is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem I design this solution

First I created a `protocol` called `WeakProtocol`, this will be our base of protocols

```
protocol WeakProtocol : AnyObject {}
```

After change your protocol to extends this new `WeakProtocol`

```
protocol Protocol: WeakProtocol {
    func function()
}
```

after your `Weak` class you need apply a `WeakProtocol` type example

```
final class Weak<Type> where Type: WeakProtocol {
    final private weak var property: Type?

    init(property: Type) {
        self.property = property
    }
}
```

Now to implement you don't need say it Protocol because the constructor receive the protocol.

Complete code is

```
protocol WeakProtocol : AnyObject {}

protocol Protocol: WeakProtocol {
    func function()
}

final class A: Protocol {
    func function() {}
}

final class Weak<Type> where Type: WeakProtocol {

    final private weak var property: Type?

    init(property: Type) {
        self.property = property
    }
}

let a = A()
let something = Weak(property: a)
```

You can too only change `Protocol` to extends `AnyObject` and `Weak` class to `Type:Protocol`, like this

```
protocol Protocol: AnyObject {
    func function()
}

final class A: Protocol {
    func function() {}
}

final class Weak<Type> where Type: Protocol {

    final private weak var property: Type?

    init(property: Type) {
        self.property = property
    }
}

let a = A()
let something = Weak(property: a)
```

Comment: interesting approach but still `let something = Weak<Protocol>(property: a)` would not work.

Comment: You don't need `<Protocol>`, if you put some object in `init(property:Type)` the `Weak` class will understand the generic type is the same.

Comment: Imagine an `Array<Weak<Protocol>>`. In that case it would not work.