# swift how to store a weak reference to a class & protocol in a generic

Tags: swift, generics, constraints, weak

I have a bunch of classes derived from UIView derivatives. Those clases also conform to protocol *commonFunctions*. I store them for further use in a dictionary, like this:

```
var elementsStore:[String:UIView & commonFunctions]
```

and protocol *commonFunctions* goes like this:

```
protocol commonFunctions:AnyObject {
    …
    func setTheme(theme:Theme);
    …
    var overrideMargins: (left:CGFloat, right:CGFloat, top:CGFloat, bottom:CGFloat) {get};
    …
}
```

I highlighted those parameters because, due to their presence, the protocol cannot be changed to @objc instead of AnyObject. That is one of the solutions I've found so far, but to no avail.

Now I need to get rid of the dictionary.
I know I can store a weak reference to such variables like this

```
weak var var1:(UIView & commonFunctions)?
```

But since there are different types of classes I need to change, I am implementing a generic. So it goes like this:

```
class WeakDictionaryData<Type:AnyObject>
{
    weak var value:Type?;
    init(_ value:Type)
    {
        self.value=value;
    }
}
```

But when I try to use the generic with the same data type *UIView & commonFunctions*, like this:

```
var var2:WeakDictionaryData<UIView & commonFunctions>
```

I get this error.

> 'WeakDictionaryData' requires that 'UIView & commonFunctions' be a class type.

I know that protocol *commonFunctions* by itself does not conform to a class type, BUT UIView does. (The not so common declaration *UIView & commonFunctions* means that such variable conforms to both the class AND the protocol, so they will always be a class type).
The only way I've found to remove that error is removing the *AnyObject* constraint from the generic, but then I get this error in the weak declaration:

> 'weak' must not be applied to non-class-bound 'Type'; consider adding a protocol conformance that has a class bound.

After a long time experimenting changes, it seems to me that the problem is the constraint in the generic, otherwise the declaration out of the generic would throw an error. But I haven't found a way to describe that constraint for the generic.
So I'm stuck.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is this the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/q/51541353/3141234 ?

Comment: Not related, but instead of passing UIView & commonFunctions everywhere, give it a type alias, and use that.

Comment: dont treat ui as data. just listen to a veteran. dont do it.

Comment: @Alexander no, it's not the same issue. Over there is the recurring question about a protocol conforming to itself. Here I have a class along with the protocol, but always a class. It should pass the generics constraint.

Comment: @TusharSharma it's a loooong project. I already got used to it. But thanks anyway

Comment: @vikingosegundo data and UI are long intertwined by the very nature of this project

Comment: @AlfredoMeraz I got a similar sense from reading the answers. I think they're mis-diagnosing the issue, even in the other question. I think you might get some better success getting help for this kinda thing from forums.swift.org. I'd suggest you slim down the example though.